# Multiple Apollo mutations

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollostack, react-apollo

I followed the [Apollo documentation](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/mutations.html#basics) to provide two mutations (`createUser` then `signInUser`) on a single React component, but one mutation (the "outer" one - signInUser) is not accessible to my code (`this.props.signInUser is not a function`). Maybe my server-side-enabled setup is masking one mutation, but I don't see where. Help appreciated :)

See full code [here](https://github.com/sedubois/realate/blob/488dcb93c0932d4eb02840f4d69e6976ac6d6014/pages/auth/callback.js).

**EDIT**: same issue when using [compose](https://github.com/apollostack/react-apollo/pull/194), see [code](https://github.com/sedubois/realate/blob/9080bd55aa71318d26bde6e02558567fcdd50d0c/pages/auth/callback.js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was caused by my `apollo` higher-order component which did more complex things than just calling Apollo's `graphql` (related to server-side rendering) and somehow must be masking properties. I bypassed this SSR behaviour for these mutations (not needed), see [code](https://github.com/sedubois/realate/blob/501876d3fa5d2517ba31f6de4279aa7f9b7c7cc1/pages/auth/callback.js#L138).

Answer (score 3):

You just need to name the mutations when passing them into the component, otherwise they are ALL called `mutate`, and override one another.

(By using the `props` function)

Here's a full example with named mutations:

https://gist.github.com/Siyfion/a2e9626ed431f8ff91af2c9b8cba1d67

Comment: Thanks but I have already renamed the mutations as instructed in the docs: `{ name: 'createUser' }` and `{ name: 'signInUser' }`. And when not providing such a name I believe the default is `mutate`, not `mutation`. Do you have a link to the Apollo documentation about this `props`?

Comment: Take a look at the second half of: http://dev.apollodata.com/react/mutations.html#calling-mutations

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use `props` but same issue. I still suspect it's something in my server-side rendering setup (my `apollo` higher-order component).